# Не работает скрипт в React.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Привет!Сегодня решил попробовать React.JS но столкнулся с проблемой того что ничего на странице не отображается.
[image: Моя страница]

Мой HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="jsx/test.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Мой JS

```
var Check;
Check = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function () {[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]
        return {checked:true}
    },
    render : function () {
        var message;
        if(this.state.checked){
            message = "выбрано";
        }else {
            message= "не выбрано";
        }
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <p>Чекбокс{message}</p>
            </div>
        )

    }

});


const app = document.getElementById("main");

ReactDom.render(<Check />,app);
```

[image: Дебагинг в WebStorm]

Comment: приветствую! во-первых, createClass давно канул в лету, поищите пожалуйста более свежие материалы по реакту. Проще всего, если хотите поиграться с реактом, или делать это здесь https://codesandbox.io/ или `npm install react-create-app`

Comment: А вы уверены что `text/babel` поддерживает jsx?

Comment: да, вроде бы поддерживает

Comment: возможно нужно переименовать test.js в test.jsx

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я знаю, с версии React@15.5 удалили React.createClass, поэтому лучше использовать ключевое слово class. В общем, почитайте [официальную документацию](https://reactjs.org/), там много полезного можно найти.

Так будет работать:

```
class Check extends React.Component {
    state = {checked: false};
    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({checked:!this.state.checked});
    }
    render() {
     let message;
     if(this.state.checked){
         message = "выбрано";
     }else {
         message= "не выбрано";
     }
     return(
         <div>
             <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
             <p>Чекбокс {message}</p>
         </div>
     );
  }
}

const app = document.getElementById("main");
ReactDOM.render(<Check />,app);
```

P.S. Обратите внимание, `ReactDOM`, а не `ReactDom`.